# Is it possible to "pass-through" GNU make jobserver environment to a submake served via a 3rd-party (non-make)

Tags: gnu-make

When running gnu-make rules with `-jN` make creates a [jobserver](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/) for managing job-count across submakes.  Additionally you can "pass the jobserver environment" to a make recipe by prefixing it with `+` - eg:

```
target :
        +./some/complex/call/to/another/make target
```

Now I instead of a sub-make I have a (python) script which runs some complex packaging actions (too complex for make).  One of the actions that it can run into can actually spawn off a `make` command.

```
package.stamp : $(DEPS)
         +./packaging.py $(ARGS)
         touch $@
```

Now when that make command is invoked inside packaging.py

```
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
```

This makes some sense because whatever environment is setup by make, may not be being honoured or passed through by python.

Is it possible to pass through the `jobserver` references through the python program to the sub-make - if so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two aspects to the jobserver that must be preserved: the first is an actual environment variable, which make uses to send options to sub-makes.  That value is being preserved properly, or else make would not know that it should even look for the jobserver and you would not see that warning message.

The second aspect are two open file descriptors which are passed to the children of make.  Your script MUST preserve these two descriptors and leave them open when it invokes the sub-make.

You don't show us what Python code is being used to invoke the sub-make.  By default, the `subprocess` module will not close file descriptors, but you can provide the `close_fds=True` option to have it do so... you should *not* use this option if you want parallel make invocations to work properly with the jobserver.

If you're not using `subprocess`, then you'll have to show us what you *are* doing.

You should probably mark this with a `python` tag as it's mainly a Python question.

Comment: Thanks - yes I had `close_fds` as true.  I'll leave python off the labels - what I wanted answered and what you did answer is "what needs to be preserved by a subprocess for the jobserver to function".  The answer environment variables and open file-descriptors is the correct answer independent of my python failing.

Comment: For anyone visiting from the future, Python's subprocess library switched to defaulting to `close_fds=True` in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise and clarify the answer - for the jobserver to work in your sub-processes you need to preserve:

- Environment variables
- The jobserver fds

One of the environment variables passed looks (for me) as follows:

```
MAKEFLAGS= --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j -- NAME=VALUE
```

`jobserver-fds` communicates which fds make has opened to communicate with the jobserver.  For the the submake to be able to use the jobserver you should thus preserve, or arrange to be available, those specific fds (or else re-write the environment variable appropriately to point them to whichever fd they end up on).

`NAME=VALUE` is arguments passed by me to the original make.

Comment: Note that up until GNU make 4.2, that flag was considered an internal behavior of GNU make and not public.  Starting with GNU make 4.2 the jobserver interface was officially published so it can be used by other tools, but along with that this option was renamed to --jobserver-auth.