# warning: jobserver unavailable when calling make from external Python script

Tags: python, bash, gnu-make

I was converting an external build script from Bash to Python, when I ran into this error. First, I run `make build -j4`, which runs a Python script to generate a list of icons to build. I pass $(MAKE) to the Python script as well, which runs `[make command passed to it] [list of icons]`. However, I get an error when doing this, which I didn't get in the Bash version.

The error I get is: `make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.`, when the Python calls `make`
I have tried adding a `+` to the rule it's called from, as well as the rules it calls, to no success.

Makefile extracts:

```
BUILD_DIR=argon
ICON_RESOLUTIONS=8 16 22 24 32 48 64 128 256

#Generates a list of svg files and png files
SVG_OBJS_ORIG = $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/scalable/*/*.svg)
SVG_OBJS = $(SVG_OBJS_ORIG) $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/scalable/*/*/*.svg)
PNG_OBJS = $(subst ./$(BUILD_DIR),./$(BUILD_DIR)/resolution,$(subst .svg,.png,$(SVG_OBJS)))
PNG_LIST = $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/*/*/*.png*)

build: autoclean
    #Generate a list of icons to build, then call make with all the icon svgs
    ./icon-builder.py --list "$(BUILD_DIR)" "$(ICON_RESOLUTIONS)" "$(MAKE)"

$(PNG_OBJS): ./$(BUILD_DIR)/resolution/%.png: ./$(BUILD_DIR)/%.svg
    mkdir -p "$(BUILD_DIR)"
    ./make-helper.sh "-i" "$@" "$(ICON_RESOLUTIONS)" "$(BUILD_DIR)"
index:
    ./generate-index.py "--index" "$(BUILD_DIR)"
```

Python extract:

```
#makeCommand is the value of $(MAKE), as that's passed to the script
#buildList is an array of each 'file' to pass to make
subprocess.run(makeCommand + buildList)
#this will ususally evaluate to something like: subprocess.run(["make", "argon/resolution/scalable/apps/openjdk-9.png", "argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.ArchiveManager.png", "index"])
```

Bash extract:

```
$makeCommand "${rebuildList[@]}"
#This would usually evalute to something like: make argon/resolution/scalable/apps/openjdk-9.png argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.ArchiveManager.png index
```

Reproducible example:
`Makefile`:

```
SHELL=bash
BUILD_DIR=argon
ICON_RESOLUTIONS=8 16 22 24 32 48 64 128 256

SVG_OBJS_ORIG = $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/scalable/*/*.svg)
SVG_OBJS = $(SVG_OBJS_ORIG) $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/scalable/*/*/*.svg)
PNG_OBJS = $(subst ./$(BUILD_DIR),./$(BUILD_DIR)/resolution,$(subst .svg,.png,$(SVG_OBJS)))
PNG_LIST = $(wildcard ./$(BUILD_DIR)/*/*/*.png*)

.PHONY: build autoclean index

build: autoclean
    #Generate a list of icons to build, then call make with all the icon svgs
    ./icon-builder.py --list "$(BUILD_DIR)" "$(ICON_RESOLUTIONS)" "$(MAKE)"
autoclean:
    #Delete broken symlinks, left over pngs and the index
    find "./$(BUILD_DIR)" -type d -empty -delete
    #External script to autoclean, no issues here
    if [[ -f "$(BUILD_DIR)/index.theme" ]]; then \
      rm "$(BUILD_DIR)/index.theme"; \
    fi
$(PNG_OBJS): ./$(BUILD_DIR)/resolution/%.png: ./$(BUILD_DIR)/%.svg
    mkdir -p "$(BUILD_DIR)"
    #External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
index:
    echo "The script that goes here works fine, and doesn't call make"
```

`icon-builder.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys

#Code to generate this left out
buildList=['argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-mines.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.Mines-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-calculator-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.Mines.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-mines-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/google-chrome.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-photos.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-calculator.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-photos-symbolic.png']
buildList.append("index")

#Add make to make arguments
makeCommand = str(sys.argv[4])
makeCommand = makeCommand.split()

#Combine make command and icons to start build
subprocess.run(makeCommand + buildList)
print(makeCommand + buildList)
```

`argon/scalable/[several dirs]/` are all filled with svgs

When running `make build -j4`, I get:

```
#Delete broken symlinks, left over pngs and the index
find "./argon" -type d -empty -delete
#External script to autoclean, no issues here
if [[ -f "argon/index.theme" ]]; then \
  rm "argon/index.theme"; \
fi
#Generate a list of icons to build, then call make with all the icon svgs
./icon-builder.py --list "argon" "8 16 22 24 32 48 64 128 256" "make"
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[1]: Entering directory '/data/ratus5/Projects/Code/test'
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
mkdir -p "argon"
#External script to build specific icon would be here, no issues there
echo "The script that goes here works fine, and doesn't call make"
The script that goes here works fine, and doesn't call make
make[1]: Leaving directory '/data/ratus5/Projects/Code/test'
['make', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-mines.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.Mines-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-calculator-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/org.gnome.Mines.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-mines-symbolic.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/google-chrome.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-photos.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-calculator.png', 'argon/resolution/scalable/apps/gnome-photos-symbolic.png', 'index']
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Including this one, I get 22 matches searching for "jobserver unavailable"!

Comment: I'll add a reproducible example, but I've tried everything relevant to my problem and I can't get them to work. Either they don't completely apply to mine, or nothing changes, so I posted here.

Comment: I fudged implementing the solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910944/is-it-possible-to-pass-through-gnu-make-jobserver-environment-to-a-submake-ser), I had to add `close_fds=False` to the subprocess command. Sorry!

Comment: Should I delete the post as it's kind of a duplicate, or post it as a solution?