# Why does sub-make only show jobserver warnings if invoked by python but not bash

Tags: python, cmake, gnu-make

Say that I have a CMake project that contains a ExternalProject target. The BUILD_COMMAND of that target executes a shell script.

```
# demo/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.1)
project(demo)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(demo
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND bash "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.sh"  
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_ALWAYS TRUE
)
```

That script invokes make:

```bash
# demo/test.sh
cd $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
make
```

which executes a simple Makefile:

```
# demo/Makefile
demo:
    echo demo
```

which yields the following warning message when building the exeternal project concurrently (`mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j8`):

```
jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add `+' to parent make rule.
```

I read from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) that if a rule contains `$(MAKE)` then it get treated specially. So I add `$(MAKE)` to the end of the BUILD_COMMAND as an attempt to remove the warning:

`BUILD_COMMAND bash "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.sh" $(MAKE)`

The warning does go away even if the newly added argument isn't actually used.

But now I want to reimplement the bash script in python:

```py
# demo/test.py
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess as sp
SCRIPT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
sp.run(['make'], cwd=SCRIPT_DIR)
```

and change the BUILD_COMMAND accordingly:

`BUILD_COMMAND python3 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.py" $(MAKE)`

The warning comes back with or without the last argument `$(MAKE)` which is not expected.

So how to explain the inconsistent behavior? Is adding a `$(MAKE)` argument an acceptable work-around for eliminating that warning? Why does that work-around only work for bash but not python?

The real project involved is much more complex than above demo. But the key idea is the same: an external project executes bash scripts to build the software that invokes make without warnings, then everything is rewritten in python and warnings emerge and I don't know how to make them disappear.

I also tried BUILD_COMMAND -> bash script -> python script -> make, i.e. modify the original bash script to call make through the python script instead of calling make directly. Warnings emerge after adding that extra python layer. So I wonder if there is somthing python does or doesn't do that makes things different. What makes the sub-make unable to recieve the complete information mentioned in the manual from the parent when invoked by python?

I also tried adding a `-j8` argument to the make command in the original bash/python script. Both scripts show warnings with or without the `$(MAKE)` argument except that the warning message is `-jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode` this time which seems to match what the manual said and thus expected.

I really want to know how to make the warnings disappear for the python script.

Comment: After @pynexj's excellent answer pointed out the correct direction, I did more digging. Apparently [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29910944/13266768) has been asked before. I also found [someone's git commit](https://archive.softwareheritage.org/browse/revision/6d4b01a1e04418e817781563b77bbf96c43c7a65/?path=build.py#swh-revision-changes) that solves the same problem with the same solution. And there is also [a post](https://www.seaxiang.com/blog/8fac9d623460449a86c78d90e2589e0b) whose scenario closely matches mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `subprocess.run(..., close_fds=False)`. The default is `close_fds=True` and according to Python's doc:

> If `close_fds` is true, all file descriptors except `0`, `1` and `2` will be closed before the child process is executed.

---

`make` opens some internal FDs which will usually be inherited to its sub-makes and these FDs are used to communicate with its sub-makes. With `subprocess.run()`'s default `close_fds=True`, these FDs will be closed so sub-makes cannot see these FDs and so the parent make cannot communicate with its sub-makes.

---

Bash (and all reasonable shells I guess) does not close these FDs before starting child processes. This is why the difference between Bash and Python's `subprocess.run()`.

---

Another solution is to use Python's `os.system()` which "is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`" which internally simply invokes `sh -c`.

Comment: Another option is to upgrade your version of GNU Make to 4.4 or above: this version uses a different implementation of jobserver by default, based on named pipes.  This means that parent make processes don't need to pass open file descriptors to their children.

Comment: Thank you! Setting close_fds=False solves my problem.